# Cannot type diacriticis with my keyboard

Tags: arch-linux, locale

Polish diacritics such as ą or ć (created with RAlt+[latin letter] combination on a `pl` keymap) cannot be typed in ArchLinux. Based on the [locale wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Locale#LANG:_default_locale), I verified that:

I generated neccessary locales by uncommenting `pl_PL.UTF8 UTF-8` and `en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8` lines in the `/etc/locale.gen` file - then ran `locale-gen` command.

I then edited `locale.conf` to have the following configuration:

```
(base) [deutschegabanna@arch ~]$ cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
KEYMAP=pl
LC_CTYPE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8
```

```
(base) [deutschegabanna@arch ~]$ localectl status
System Locale: LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
               LC_CTYPE=pl_PL.UTF-8
               LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8
               LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8
               LC_COLLATE=pl_PL.UTF-8
               LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8
               LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8
               LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8
               LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8
               LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: pl2
   X11 Layout: pl
```

I obviously restarted the system to load the new `locale.conf` and can see that at least dates work (they are displayed in Polish), whereas interface language remains English (that's also good).

However, diacritics still cannot be typed from my keyboard on any software in ArchLinux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us exactly what keyboard combinations you use to try to type the diacritics, that way we'll know what to attempt and might be able to point out an obvious error if there is one.

Comment: Done, thank you for pointing it out.